# noting work RewriteEngine online

Tags: php, get, url-rewriting

i use rewrite for link

in local this code work fine but noting work online

htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/$ page.php?id=$1
```

php code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !=""){
echo $_GET['id'];
} else {
echo "Empty"
}
```

on host error EMPTY but on local echo get id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error form server

manager set apache and this error solved

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your server configuration.

**mod_rewrite** module may not be enabled in your server or **rewrite_url** will not supported

check your server appache config by using [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

contact your hosting support. if your hosting support is **BIGROCK** they are note support this feature

Comment: brother, its better to contact your Hosting support. i didnt find any mistake in your .htaccess. i have already faced this problem and my server also enabled **mod_rewrite**. But they dont support **rewrite** instead they support **redirect**.

Comment: i contact hosting support and reply : mod_rewrite active on server